# GWT 2.6.1 CellList MediaQuery

Tags: html, css, gwt

I'm wondering if it's possible to use media queries with CellLists. For example:

```
interface MyStyle extends Style {
}

public interface MyResources extends Resources {
    @Source({ Style.DEFAULT_CSS, "MyStyle.css" })
    MyStyle cellListStyle();
}
```

And then I have the CellList CSS file "MyStyle.css" :

```
/* cell flow basic css style */
.cellListWidget {

}

.cellListEvenItem {

}

.cellListOddItem {

}

.cellListEvenItem:hover,.cellListOddItem:hover {

}

.cellListKeyboardSelectedItem,.cellListSelectedItem:hover {

}

.cellListSelectedItem {

}
```

Is it possible to have something like this

```
@media ( min-width : 768px) {
    .cellListEvenItem {
        height: 90px;
    }
}
```

inside MyStyle.css ? I tried and it doesn't seem to recognize it (no errors or warnings, but it doesn't work either).

I used it like this:

```
new CellList<MyObject>(listCell,
                (CellList.Resources) GWT.create(MyResources.class));
```

If the above is not possible is there any workaround to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: can you put your code in snippet for better understanding.

Comment: As far as I can see in my browser the code is inside the snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS Resource didn't allow to use CSS3 media queries.
You must use the new stylesheet compiler named GSS in the GWT version 2.7.

You must update your project to the version 2.7.

In your gwt.xml add this line for activate the new GSS :

```
<set-configuration-property name="CssResource.enableGss" value="true" />
```

And rename your css file to MyStyle.gss

You may need to change some CSS Resource code :
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideGssVsCss.html

You can learn more in the presentation from last GwtCreate :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwVGJUurq6uVNGgtOWtOdy0wRzQ/view

Comment: Thank you Patrice. Unfortunatelly this does not help me at all because updating a large project to the latest GWT version 2.7 is not possible at the moment (they are not making it easy to update). But I will mark your answer as being correct

Comment: The update to GWT 2.7 works very well on my many large project.
Otherwise, you must use an external stylesheet for have media queries.